# What's the difference between XY=F and XY=0 in Jeffrey's Logic of Decision?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-science, probability

I'm stuck solving problem 14 in Chapter 5 of Jeffrey's Logic of Decision.

The first part of the problem says:

> Show that in presence of *prob* is nonnegative (prob X≥0) and *prob*
>   is normalized (T=1),
>
> (5-1) (c) if XY=F, then *prob* (X∨Y) = *prob* X + *prob* Y **implies**
>
> (5-1) (h) if *prob* XY=0, then *prob* (X∨Y) = *prob* X + *prob* Y **but
>   not viceversa.**
>
> (Hint: what if *prob* assigned the value 1 to all propositions?).

I don't understand because Jeffrey says (page 76) that *prob* F=0. So both 5-1 (c) and (h) would be identical.

The other part of the problem is that I wouldn't know the procedure to prove *this* implication. A truth table seems cumbersome and inadequate. I suppose there's a better way.

Would appreciate any help regarding both the difference between XY=F and XY=0 or the procedure to prove the implication.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Was the question copied correctly? I'm not sure what "presence of" would mean here, and it seems like prob can't be its object.

Comment: Yes, I checked. It says "Show that in the presence of (5-1) (a,b),...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [page 76](https://books.google.it/books?id=geJ-SwTcmyEC&pg=PA76) :

> For the impossible proposition, the proposition which is false in all cases, we shall use the special symbol **F** and set
>
> > **prob F=0**.

Thus, to say that **XY=F** means to say that **XY** is never true.

Axiom 5-1(c) says :

> prob is additive: if **XY = F**, then **prob (X v Y) = prob X + prob Y**.

See page 81; using Ax.5-1(c), Jeffrey proves (5-1)(g) :

> **prob (A v B) = prob A + prob B - prob AB**.

Thus, if we assume **prob AB=0**, using (5-1)(g) [that derives from (5-1)(c)] we conclude that :

> **prob (A v B) = prob A + prob B**.

---

The "Hint : what if prob assigned the value **1** to all propositions?" allows us to check the difference between (5-1)(c) and (5-1)(h).

Consider : (5-1)(d). We have **AA' = F** [I've used **A'** for the denial of **A**] and we can set **X = A** and **Y = A'** in (5-1)(h) [now we have it instead of (5-1)c)] to get ...

And here we are stuck; if all propositions have **prob = 1**, then also **prob AA' = 1** and thus from the fact that **AA' = F** we cannot deduce that **prob AA' = 0** and thus we cannot apply the antecedent of (5-1)(h), i.e. **prob AA'=0**, to derive the fundamental :

> > **prob A' = 1 - prob A**.

In fact, if all propositions have **prob =1**, then : **prob A = prob A'=1**.